# Format a new Date() to EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date/time displayed using "new date()".

It currently displays

```
"Thu May 31 2012 13:04:29 GMT-0500 (CDT)".
```

I need this:

```
 "Thu May 31 13:04:29 CDT 2012".
```

How do I format it?

Comment: What do you mean by zzz?

Comment: So here zzz is `CDT` ?

Comment: Check https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: How do I do without a plugin sir?

Comment: JavaScript native date/time handling is still very primitive. You would be better off using a plugin than reinventing the wheel. I suggest using Moment.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to extract the timezone from the standard date string.

```
var d            = new Date();
var customFormat = d.toString().slice(0,7) + ' ' +              //Day and Month
                   d.getDate() + ' ' +                          //Day number
                   d.toTimeString().slice(0,8) + ' ' +          //HH:MM:SS
                   /\(.*\)/g.exec(d.toString())[0].slice(1,-1)  //TimeZone
                   + ' '  + d.getFullYear();                    //Year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new Date();
    var fp = a.toDateString().substring(0, a.toDateString().length - 4);
    var sp = a.toLocaleTimeString();
    var tp = a.toDateString().substr(a.toDateString().length - 5);
    $('.timer').html(fp + ' ' + sp + ' ' + tp);
```

Comment: for me the output is `Wed Mar 12 2014 15:56:46 GMT+0500 (West Asia Standard Time)`

Comment: but @Vidya wants something like this `Thu May 31 13:04:29 CDT 2012`

Comment: Sir this doesnt give me the required output

Comment: @Roger sir
    http://jsfiddle.net/zJsCF/
here is the jsfiddle for the above code which you gave.
EVerything works fine except for the timezone. How do i fix it?

Comment: This is local time and gets different timezone on each terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the string always has the format in your example:

```
var s = "Thu May 31 2012 13:04:29 GMT-0500 (CDT)";
var a = s.split(/ /);

s = a[0] + " " + a[1] + " " + a[2] + " " + a[4] + " " + a[6].substring(1, a[6].length - 1) + " " + a[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

The moment.js library is great for formatting dates and times. 
http://momentjs.com/

Ex:
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // July 14th 2015, 9:29:52 am

Answer (score -1):

```
// timeStamp  EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy
const timeArr = new Date().toString().split('+')[0].split(' ');
const timeStamp = timeArr.slice(0, 3).concat(timeArr.slice(4), timeArr[3]).join(' ');
```

timeArr creates an array split by space. The second line re-arrange the order of the array to achieve this format => (EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy) by using slice and concat function. Lastly, use join to convert it back to string.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.