# Format date() to eee,dd MMM YYYY,hh:mm:ss in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is quite similar to Stack Overflow question *[Format a new Date() to EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347724/format-a-new-date-to-eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-zzz-yyyy)*.

But here I need a date format something like:

```
   "Fri, 23 May 2014, 09:03:29"
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "javascript format datetime"?  The [second result](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) has a useful little tool

Comment: Try http://momentjs.com/ - A javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.

Comment: @Coda17 the solution worked. using http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format had provided the desired result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. I hope it works!

```
var timeString = myDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (myDate.getMonth()+1) + '-'
+ myDate.getDate() + ' ' + myDate.getHours() + ':' + myDate.getMinutes() + ':' 
+ myDate.getSeconds();
```

Comment: It working fine in IE and Mozilla browser.But not in Google chrome.

Comment: That not going to get the name of the day or month

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.toString().split("GMT")[0]);
```

Just split the GMT from your date object string

Comment: I need for Indian time zone.

Comment: With the `new Date()` it will get the local time from your time zone and just split the string and use the front part.

Answer (score 0):

A function like this can solve the problem:

```
function formatDate(myDate) {
    var abbrMonths = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var abbrDays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    function zeroPadding(val) {
        return val.toString().length === 1 ? "0" + val : val;
    }

    return abbrDays[myDate.getDay()] + ", " + myDate.getDate() + " " + (abbrMonths[myDate.getMonth()]) +
        " " + myDate.getFullYear() + ", " + zeroPadding(myDate.getHours()) + ":" +
        zeroPadding(myDate.getMinutes()) + ":" + zeroPadding(myDate.getSeconds());
}
```

To get the formatted date just pass your date into the function like so:

```
var formattedDate = formatDate(new Date());
```

[Moment](http://momentjs.com/) is a plugin made especially for formatting and calculating dates. Perhaps it can also help you if you're looking on formatting dates in multiple ways.